# function triggers on window width but will not turn off if bigger than set width

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Here is what I have now it will work but if window width is under 1024 it will still trigger even though it is only set to trigger if over 1024

```
$(function () {

    $('#hamburger').click(function () {
        $('div.burger_nav').slideToggle();
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
            $('.nav_shown').hide();
            $('div.footerdiv_2').hide();
            $('div.hidden_nav').hide();
            $('div.burger_btn').show();
            $('#ft').removeClass('footerdiv_3').addClass('footer_img_clear');
        } //end of if

        else {
            $(".nav_shown").show();
            $('.footerdiv_2').show();
            $('div.burger_btn').hide();
            $('#ft').removeClass('footer_img_clear').addClass('footerdiv_3');

            $(document).scroll(function () {
                var headerShow = $(this).scrollTop();
                if (headerShow > 200) {
                    $('div.hidden_nav').fadeIn();
                    $(".nav_shown").hide();
                } else {
                    $('div.hidden_nav').fadeOut();
                    $(".nav_shown").show();
                }
            });
        } //end of else
    });
});
```

Comment: you're not triggering it

Comment: The `else` part of your `if` statement will trigger every time the window is resized and is greater than 1024, is this your intent? Or do you only want the `else` part to trigger once when going from < 1024 to > 1024?

Comment: You're binding a new [`.scroll()`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event handler to the document on every resize. Looks like you want to use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)/[`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) instead (or possibly even [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)?)

Comment: Consider using a form of debounce if you're going to utilize resize and scroll events. http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/debounce/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to modify the document when the window reaches a certain breakpoint, in this case 1024 pixels. This is known as responsive web design.

Instead of updating the screen every time on resize, it's useful to set a flag for triggering a breakpoint.

```
$(function() {

    $('#hamburger').click(function(){
        $('div.burger_nav').slideToggle();
    });

    var currentlySmall = false;
    function update() {
        if ($(window).width() < 1024 && !currentlySmall) {
            currentlySmall = true;
            console.log('Less than 1024');

            $('.nav_shown').hide();
            $('div.footerdiv_2').hide();
            $('div.hidden_nav').hide();
            $('div.burger_btn').show();
            $('#ft').removeClass('footerdiv_3').addClass('footer_img_clear');
        }
        else if ($(window).width() >= 1024 && currentlySmall) {
            currentlySmall = false;
            console.log('More than 1024');

            $(".nav_shown").show();
            $('.footerdiv_2').show();
            $('div.burger_btn').hide();
            $('#ft').removeClass('footer_img_clear').addClass('footerdiv_3');
        }
    }

    //Calling this in the else part above will bind a new scroll event each time
    //Instead, if this should only happen when the screen is large, use the 
    //flag you created
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        if (!currentlySmall) {
            var headerShow = $(this).scrollTop();
            if (headerShow > 200) {
                $('div.hidden_nav').fadeIn();
                $(".nav_shown").hide();
            } else {
                $('div.hidden_nav').fadeOut();
                $(".nav_shown").show();
            }
        }
    });

    $(window).resize(update);
    update(); //Force initial calculation since resize won't be called when page loads
});
```

Now the changes you make in the above `update()` function will only occur when the screen sizes changes past that 1024 breakpoint instead of every time the screen is resized.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/25nfqxzk/1/

**Edit**
Expanding off blgt's comment, I don't believe you need to bind the scroll event in the if-else. It can be assigned outside and also use the same trigger flags.